# Is there a way to create JAXB binding rules based on regex for all xsds? (as opposed to a rule per schema file)

Tags: regex, jaxb

I'm using xjc (jaxb2-maven-plugin) to generate my POJOs from several XSD files.  Not surprisingly, there are class conflicts if I put all my generated files into one package.  By default xjc will use the namespace as a package name.

Ex:

```
namespace: "https://analysiscenter.domain.com/schema/4.0/sandboxlist"
becomes package: https.analysiscenter_domain_com.schema._4_0.sandboxlist
```

I realize that I can use xjc:bindings to specify individually which namespace becomes which package, but that becomes quite tedious.  Is there any way to specify rules or regexs for the bindings for all xsds?

Ex: namespace .*/schema/(.*)/(.*) becomes package: myDefaultPackage.$1.$2

Ex something like the following:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="*.xsd" node="/xsd:schema[@value=.*/schema/(.*)/(.*)">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="com.domain.$1.$2"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to specify rules or regexs for the bindings for all xsds?

No, you can't use regexes or similar. But I think you should be able to write an own implementation of the `com.sun.xml.bind.api.impl.NameConverter` and register it in `com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.setNameConverter(...)` via XJC plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately that's what I had expected. I think my own NameConverter is getting too advanced for my needs (and the people who will need to support it).  I'll just end up doing a lot of cut & paste in my bindings.